# How would a particle travel in a hurricane?

Tags: meteorology, wind, tropical-cyclone, natural-disasters, particulates

How would a particle other then water travel in a hurricane? At what buoyancy or height would [a small air born life preserver](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/110241/could-this-bubble-float-with-a-person-inside) be safe from the ground in a hurricane? How fun would that be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find [diagrams of air flow in hurricanes](https://www.google.com/search?q=air+flow+hurricane&client=ubuntu&hs=7gc&channel=fs&source=lnms&tbm=isch). If your balloon has neutral buoyancy it will go with the flow. Good luck in the complicated currents in the rainbands and eyewall.